# Angular typed controls No seeing types

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, eslint, angular-forms

I am working updating some legacy forms to be more strongly typed and thus fix eslint errors.  I keep running into issues where the `.value` operator on abstract controls throws an IDE error "Unsafe member access .value on an `any` value." which violates my projects [no-unsafe-member-access](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access/). For example:

```
// strong typing from the start
interface sampleForm {
   account_1: FormControl<string>;
   account_2: FormControl<string>;
};

// Form builder
this.myForm: sampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   account_1: new FormControl<string|null>("placeholder", [Validators.maxLength(128),]),
   accounte_2: new FormControl<string|null>("", [Validators.maxLength(128),]),
});

// the problem, "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value", "Unsafe member access .value on an `any` value."
const t = this.myForm.controls[`account_${1}].value;
```

I have tried using `controls.controlName.getRawValue()`, `controls.get(controlName)`, `controls.controlName.value as string`, `let t = controls.controlName as AbstractControl; t = t.value as string;`  All throw the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const t = (this.myForm.controls[`account_${1}`] as FormControl<string>).value;
```

Using type assertion (this.myForm.controls[account_${1}] as FormControl), TypeScript knows that control is indeed of type FormControl, so accessing its value property is safe.

Comment: That works!  Not the prettiest.  Why have typed forms if you still need to cast with `as`.